# How can I remove the shadow that’s included on product images? BIG CARTEL

Tags: css, themes, bigcartel

I am using the Luna theme on big cartel, but when viewing on a mobile device the products become difficult to see due to the box shadow. I came across a help page from big cartel that suggested copying a code into the CSS but this did not change it. The code was as follows:

```
#product_images li img {
  box-shadow: none;
  webkit-box-shadow: none
}
```

Is this code correct or is there another way I could change this?

Comment: That code only removes the outer box shadow on the product images when you're viewing the store on larger screens. I think you're looking to remove the overlay background color on mobile, so the image just has the white text on top of the image - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `!important` to make sure the code in your CSS is being overridden. You were also missing the `#` before the `product_images` and the `-` before the `webkit` which might be part of the problem.

```
#product_images li img {
    box-shadow: none !important; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You need to add '-' in front of webkit-box-shadow.